# How to receive user input from FilteredSelectMultiple widget?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create form using FilteredSelectMultiple widget. I managed to get it showing on my page, but faced difficulties receiving user input from it. For now, after I click `submit` button page just refresh and shows same form again instead of going to designated page. What I am doing wrong?

My code so far:

forms.py

```
class DrgSkaiciuokle(forms.Form):
    drg_pasirinkimas = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=DRGkodas.objects.all(),
                                                      label="Pasirinkite atvejį sudarančius DRG",
                                                      widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("DRG kodai", is_stacked=False),
                                                      required=True)

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('/static/admin/css/widgets.css',),
        }
        js = ('/admin/jsi18n',)

    #I have no idea if this part is right:
    def clean_drg_pasirinkimas(self):
        drg_pasirinkimas = self.cleaned_data['drg_pasirinkimas']
        return drg_pasirinkimas
```

views.py

```
def DRG_skaiciuokle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DrgSkaiciuokle(request.POST)
        pasirinkti_DRG = form.cleaned_data['drg_pasirinkimas']

        context = {
            'pasirinktiDRG': pasirinktiDRG,
            }
        #This page should be opened after submitting form instead of refresh    
        return render(request, 'DRGskaiciuokle_valid.html', context)

    else:
        form = DrgSkaiciuokle()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'DRGskaiciuokle.html', context)
```

my html file:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div id='frame'>
    <div id='sk_head'>
        <h3>Kaštų konvertavimo skaičiuoklė</h3>
        <h4>Pagal DRG metodiką</h4>
    </div>
    <form>
        <div id='sk_body'>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Įveskite duomenis</legend>      
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <table>
                        {{ form.media }}
                        {{ form.as_table }}
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'jsi18n' %}"></script>
                    </table>
                        <input type="submit" value="Skaičiuoti">
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you don't set the method on your `<form>` tag to "post", it'll be submitted with GET, so you never reach the `if request.method == 'POST'`. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/) to learn about forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code as follow

1. Update **html** file.

   There is a form inside a form. You need to remove the inner form and update the outer form as suggested below.

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div id='frame'>
    <div id='sk_head'>
        <h3>Kaštų konvertavimo skaičiuoklė</h3>
        <h4>Pagal DRG metodiką</h4>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">  # <-----------------add action and method here
        <div id='sk_body'>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Įveskite duomenis</legend>      
                <form>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <table>
                        {{ form.media }}
                        {{ form.as_table }}
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'jsi18n' %}"></script>
                    </table>
                        <input type="submit" value="Skaičiuoti">
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

2. Inside **views.py**

   Add `form.is_valid()` the method call to check whether the form is valid or not.

```
def DRG_skaiciuokle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DrgSkaiciuokle(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pasirinkti_DRG = form.cleaned_data['drg_pasirinkimas']

            context = {
            'pasirinktiDRG': pasirinktiDRG,
            }
            #This page should be opened after submitting form instead of refresh    
            return redirect('redirect_to_view') # <------------ redirect ot url on success
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'DRGskaiciuokle.html', context)
    else:
        form = DrgSkaiciuokle()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'DRGskaiciuokle.html', context)
```

I think this would help. For clarification DM.

Comment: Note that it's bad practice to return an HTML page with status 200 on successful POST, because this causes people to resubmit the same data when reloading the page in their browser. You should **always** redirect in this case.

Comment: Yes! noted, you are right about that. I've changed the answer accordingly. Thank you for a suggestion.